# I need to generate records for current week based on today's date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to generate records for date, In time and out time for current week based on todays date and empcode(Sql server 2008 r2),when a user clicks Current week in  dropdownlist in asp.net web application.

I have stored procedure like this:

```
select @empcode as empcode, 
  min(eventdate) as firstIn, 
  max(eventdate) as lastout 
from eurevents 
where empcode = @empcode 
  and convert(Varchar,logdate,110) = convert(Varchar, @searchdate, 110);
```

I am a trainee newly joined. so please help me out

Comment: where is the rest of the stored proc? you have the variable @searchdate yet i cant see it used anywhere. Also you have firstin and lastout that i can see used anywhere and i cant see andy reference to a daytetime search eg GETDATE(). can you please provide some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code will bring you back all records within the current week. If you only want the working week (without weekends) change the *7 and +7 to *5 and +5

```
 BETWEEN dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7,-53684) 
    AND dateadd(dd((datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7)+7,-53684)
```

Comment: I am unable to fetch records from the below sp

Comment: my sp is:select EmpCode,EventDate1 as EventDate,InTime,
case when OutTime is null then 'N/A' else Outtime end as OutTime from    
TMS_HOURCALC WHERE intime1
  BETWEEN dateadd(dd,(datediff(DD,-53684,getdate())/7)*7,-53684) 
    AND dateadd(dd,((datediff(dd,-53684,getdate())/7)*7)+7,-53684) and 
    empcode = '13658' 
       
GROUP BY EmpCode, InTime,OutTime, EventDate1,intime1     
order by intime1;

Comment: what error do you get?...... also i can see you end before setting as with endtime. could you edit your post for me to show your tables and i can fix this

Comment: Query executed successfully but no records fetched!